# HTML button object not going to the intended link

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to test my website by using the buttons that I've coded, one of which should take me back to the homepage of my website. However, when I press this button, the page seems to simply refresh and remain where it is (I am not returned to the homepage).

I've checked the names of all of the provided functions/links to make sure that I am giving the button the correct destination.

Below is the code for my "upload" page, which should allow the user to upload a name and a file.

```
<div id="form">
            <form action="{{ url_for('algorithm') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="algo-header"><h1><u>New Algorithm:</u></h1></div>
                <div id="field-names">
                    User Name:
                    <br><br><br>
                    Algorithm:
                </div>
                <div id="fields">
                    <input class="text" type = "text" name = "usr" />
                    <br><br><br>
                    <input class="text" type="file" id="file" name="file" />
                </div>
                <div id="buttons">
                    <br>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" style="width: 60px" value="Submit" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button id="home-button" class="submit" style="width: 130px">Return to Homepage</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("home-button").onclick =
                function() {
                    location.href = "{{ url_for('welcome') }}";
                };
        </script>
```

And below is my "welcome" function in the main app of my website:

```
@app.route("/")
def welcome():
    rows = get_all_algos()
    return render_template("index.html", rows=rows)
```

And here is the "algorithm" function which takes me to the "/algorhithm" page:

```
@app.route("/algorithm", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def algorithm():
    print('entrypoint')
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form["file"] != "":
            try:
                print('link-friend')
                usr = request.form["usr"]
                ln = request.form["file"]

                with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
                    c = con.cursor()
                    c.execute("INSERT INTO algorithms (user, source) VALUES (?,?)", (usr, ln))
                    con.commit()
                    msg = "Algorithm Added Successfully"
            except:
                con.rollback()
                msg = "Error in adding algorithm"
            finally: 
                return render_template("results.html", msg=msg)
                con.close()
        else:
            if "file" not in request.files:
                flash("No file part")
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files["file"]
            if file.filename == "":
                flash("No selected file")
                return redirect(request.url)
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                usr = request.form["usr"]
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                print(file.filename)
                print(filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
                c = con.cursor()
                c.execute("INSERT INTO algorithms (user, source) VALUES (?,?)", (usr, filename))
                con.commit()
                msg = "Algorithm Added Successfully"
                return render_template("results.html", msg=msg)
                con.close()
               # return redirect(url_for("uploaded_file",
               #                       filename=filename))
    return render_template("new_algo.html")
```

When I click on the button (which is on a webpage with the route "/algorithm"), I should be taken back to the index/home page ("/"), however, I remain on "/algorithm".

*Note: I am using Flask, which is why I use `{{ url_for() }}` format for links.

Comment: Try to fix a typo onClick -> onclick. Info https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Thanks, the code has been updated.

Comment: Why have you made home-button `type=submit` if you don't want it, actually, to submit?

Comment: That is a separate Submit button above the home-button. I made them both class "submit" for the purpose of formatting, but I don't believe I made the home-button have `type=submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses, but I believe I've solved the issue. It appears that keeping within the `<form>` section of the code forced its functionality to match that of the form (when pressed, the page was submitted, bring up the `/algorithm` script again, keeping me on the same page.

Moving the `<button>` object to *outside* the `<form>` section solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting from your "form action" ('algorithm') function instead of using html.

```
return redirect('/welcome')
```

Comment: I edited the quesiton to include my "algorithm" function. I don't see what you mean by redirecting from the function instead of using html.

Comment: In the algorithm function you have return render_template("new_algo.html"). new_algo.html is the page that will get rendered when you press the button. If you want it to go to /welcome simply replace "new_algo.html" with "welcome.html" or as my answer states use return redirect('/welcome')

Comment: And this is true even though that return statement is only used in case of GET method on algorithm? I assumed that would only be rendered when I first go the "/algorithm" link, with the button itself pointing to the `welcome()` function.

Comment: If that is what you want you should intent the return statement into your else condition. Otherwise you will return the new_algo regardless because it is now outside the scope of the else condition.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I still face the same problem. The page does not redirect.

Comment: Did you try placing the return redirect inside: the if request.method == "POST": statement?

Comment: I did. No luck.

Comment: I’m not great at JavaScript but maybe try removing the “button” script since Flask is handling that for you.